# problem with including categorical variables newdata argument

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to plot the results from a linear probability model that plots the probability of an event based on participant gender and another variable (prs_ea_ALL). I am running into an error message (see below) when I include the categorical variable "intyorn." I don't understand why that is. Can someone please help me fix this?

```
data2$gender =as.factor(data2$gender)

data2$intyorn =as.factor(data2$intyorn)

data2$EducAge20Recoded =as.factor(data2$EducAge20Recoded)

mylogit <- glm(EducAge20Recoded ~ gender + intyorn+ prs_ea_all + gxeaALL, data = data2, family = "binomial")

data3 <- with(data2, data.frame(prs_ea_all = mean(prs_ea_all), **intyorn**, gxeaALL = mean(gxeaALL), gender = factor(0:1)))

data3$genderP <- predict(mylogit, newdata = data3, type = "response")

newdata2 <- with(data2, data.frame(prs_ea_all = rep(seq(from = -4, to = 4, length.out = 100), ##2), gxeaALL = mean(gxeaALL), intyorn, gender = factor(rep(0:1, each = 100))))
```

> Error in data.frame(prs_ea_all = rep(seq(from = -4, to = 4, length.out = 100),  : 
>    arguments imply differing number of rows: 200, 1, 1050

Comment: Supply the correct length to the `rep` call. This has nothing to do with logistic regression. And it has nothing to do with `intyorn` eitehr. Please read the error message more carefully.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. I'm relatively new to R. I don't understand what you mean by specifying the correct length for the rep call. I checked a few websites (e.g., https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/glm) and I can't seem to figure it out. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post a reproducible example, I will create some mock data to illustrate the error.
What is happening is that when you try to build a data frame, you have vectors of different lengths.
Here is a simple example that will result in the same error

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
z <- 1:23
a <- 1:73

data.frame(x,y,z,a)
```

Error in data.frame(x, y, z, a) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 23, 73

Now, looking at your example closer, I can see some problems with the following variables:

1st)
prs_ea_all

Here you repeat seq(from = -4, to = 4, length.out = 100) twice, which generates a vector of 200 elements

2nd) 
gxeaALL
With this variable you want the mean of a variable, which is a vector with a single number

3rd) 
intyorn appears to be a vector of length 1050, check your original data to certify.

### In Summary

Make sure that all of your vectors in your data frame function call have the same number of elements. Like the example below:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
z <- 1:100
a <- 1:100

data.frame(x,y,z,a)
```